# Fluentd tail config for HashiCorp Vault audit/server logs from stdout

Tags: logging, helm, fluentd

I'm trying to figure out a way to get both the audit and server logs from HasiCorp Vault container (both logs go to stdout of the same container and they have a different structure):

Audit example:

```
2024-02-11T15:24:37.298119887Z stdout F {"time":"2024-02-11T15:24:37.297967585Z","type":"request","auth":{"client_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","accessor":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","display_name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","policies":["default","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],"token_policies":["default","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],"policy_results":{"allowed":true,"granting_policies":[{"name":"default","namespace_id":"root","type":"acl"}]},"metadata":{"role":"xxxxxxxxxxx","service_account_name":"xxxxx","service_account_namespace":"xxxxxxxxxx","service_account_secret_name":","namespace":{"id":"root"},"path":"auth/token/lookup-self","remote_address":"XXXXXXX","remote_port":XXXXX}}
```

Server example:

```
2024-02-11T15:50:06.857506784Z stderr F {"@level":"info","@message":"pipelining replication","@module":"storage.raft","@timestamp":"2024-02-11T15:50:06.857384Z","peer":{"Suffrage":0,"ID":"vault-0","Address":"vault-0.vault-internal:8201"}}
```

Current configuration (from [Helm](https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/fluentd/values.yaml):

```
fileConfigs:
  01_sources.conf: |-
    ## logs from podman
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_vault_logs
      @label @KUBERNETES
      path /var/log/containers/vault-1_vault_vault*.log,/var/log/containers/vault-2_vault_vault*.log,/var/log/containers/vault-3_vault_vault*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      refresh_interval 10
      max_line_size 500000
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_key time
          time_type string
          time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L"
          keep_time_key false
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (.))? (?<log>.*)$/
          time_format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L'
          keep_time_key false
        </pattern>
      </parse>
      emit_unmatched_lines true
    </source>
  02_filters.conf: |-
    <label @KUBERNETES>
      <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.fluentd**>
        @type relabel
        @label @FLUENT_LOG
      </match>

      <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**_kube-system_**>
        @type null
        @id ignore_kube_system_logs
      </match>

      <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type parser
        key_name log
        format json
        reserve_data true
      </filter>

      <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
        @id filter_kube_metadata
        skip_labels false
        skip_container_metadata false
        skip_namespace_metadata true
        skip_master_url true
      </filter>

      <match **>
        @type relabel
        @label @DISPATCH
      </match>
    </label>
  03_dispatch.conf: |-
    <label @DISPATCH>
      <filter **>
        @type prometheus
        <metric>
          name fluentd_input_status_num_records_total
          type counter
          desc The total number of incoming records
          <labels>
            tag ${tag}
            hostname ${hostname}
          </labels>
        </metric>
      </filter>

      <match **>
        @type relabel
        @label @OUTPUT
      </match>
    </label>
  04_outputs.conf: |-
    <label @OUTPUT>
      <match **>
        @type opensearch
        host ${fluentd_opensearch_host}
        port ${fluentd_opensearch_port}
        user ${fluentd_opensearch_username}
        password ${fluentd_opensearch_password}
        logstash_format true
        logstash_prefix vault.${tag}
        scheme https
        ssl_verify false
      </match>
    </label>
```

By now I think I've tried everything and have not managed to get it working. I want to match each type separately and also send them to a separate index, vault.audit- and vault.server- respectively. Output is opensearch but that part is fine. I'm just struggling with the concept of where I have to do what. Should be stupid simple and probably is but I just can't wrap my head around it... Fluentd is deployed via helm chart version 0.5.0 [Fluentd](https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/fluentd/values.yaml) as a daemonset.